# PHP auto_prepend_file define a constant

Tags: php

I do have configured a auto_prepend_file in my .htaccess. It works fine!
Now I wanted to know how to make a string globally without using GLOBALS.

I do have something like this:

```
define('WWW_URL', 'http://www.xyz.de');
define('STATIC_URL', 'http://static.xyz.de');
```

How do I get the WWW_URL or STATIC_URL in my index.php which is loaded right after the prepend and before append file?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Like any other constant. `echo WWW_URL;`. Where variables would be prepended with `$` (eg. `$foo`), constants are just their name (eg. `STATIC_URL`).

Comment: Something goes wrong with those constants?

Comment: Thanks @h2ooooooo! Unfortunately you made a comment instead of an answer, so i just could upvote it.

Comment: @webprogrammer That's completely fine. I usually do not post an answer for simple answers, as I feel I'll lack details. A comment can answer a question in 30 characters, but an answer needs more depth in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.

From [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

So you can access the constants inside your `index.php` using `WWW_URL` / `STATIC_URL`.

Beware constants are read-only: you won't be able to change their value after you "`define()`" them, unlike `GLOBALS` variables.